# CSS unhover property with @keyframes

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I want to yse animation of my menu with @keyframes. But if page load i have yellow link that animate to grey ( "@keyframes exa" start automaticaly but i dont need that first start). And only after that its work exactly what i want.

```css
.top-menu {
  position: relative;
  background: rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.2);
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu-main {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu-main a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 80px;
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-family: "Arimo", sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  animation-name: exa;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

.menu-main a:hover {
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

@keyframes example {
  from {
    background: rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.2);
  }
  to {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
}

@keyframes exa {
  from {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  to {
    background: rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.2);
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav class="top-menu">
    <ul class="menu-main">
      <li><a href="">Work</a></li>
      <li><a href="">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Story</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Shop</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</body>
```

I expected that page load with grey link, and after if I hover it's come to yellow and back if I unhover link, use @keyframes and if it`s possible - without JS.

Comment: You should be using `transition:` for this, not `animation:`.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't be mixing shorthand and longhand properties in an animation like that, because the shorthand properties will overwrite all of their longhand properties.

Comment: I know about transition, but what about animation?

Comment: I whant use animation with @keyframes. Not transition

Comment: and get unhover animation without transition. Because animation i can devide to smaller part (25,50%...).